# no response form ajax and responseText is undefined

Tags: php, ajax

I've been trying to get ajax to work the whole day and this my last hope, i wrote a simple test to see if i get any response, the xhr.status is 0 instead of 200, and the xhr.responseText is undefinded. I call a simple (php file) which generates a json object, my code is as follows(i tried using $.ajax but it didnt help either):

```
$(function(){

$('#checkin').click(function(){
var ajaxRequest;
var connection  = ajaxFunction();
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "places.php", true);
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

    alert(console.error(ajaxRequest.status));
    }
}

ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
});

})
```

and my php file is as follows:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require "SQLquery.php";

$places = new SQLquery;
$places->db_query("SELECT * FROM places");
echo json_encode($places->results);

?>
```

any help will be much appreciated. Thanx

Comment: Wait a second, so how does your PHP file correlate to your AJAX initiation?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jQuery ajax functions?

Comment: well ajax is sending a request to the php file, and the file echoes a echoes json_encoded output which is like this:
 [{"place_id":1,"place_name":"Patidos","place_type_id":0,"street":"J abavu Street","suburb":"New Brighton","city":"Port Elizabeth","country":"South Africa"},{"place_id":2,"place_name":"Zanzibar","place_type_id":1,"street":"Long Street","suburb":"Central","city":"Port Elizabeth","country":"South Africa"}]
@Uby do u have any suggesting on how can use the jQuery Ajax functions because when i used them i couldn't even get the "alert" function to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation using jQuery's $.ajax() and json.

Javascript:

```
function sendAjax() {

    // The data you want to pass to places.php
    var params = {
        'checkin' : true
    };

    // Construct the call
    ajax = $.ajax({
        url: '/places.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: params,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    // Send it and say which function you'll
    // use to handle the response
    ajax.done(sendAjaxDone);
}

// Handle the response
function sendAjaxDone(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

places.php

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
require "SQLquery.php";

if ($_GET['checkin']) {
    $places = new SQLquery;
    $places->db_query("SELECT * FROM places");
    echo json_encode($places->results);
}
```

Comment: and how do I access the response so that I can work with under //success?

Comment: I tried that code and I'm not getting any sort of output, not even alert() seems to be working,

Comment: I've edited the response function because it relied on a status being passed which I use in my own code but didn't include in this example. Check the console in your browser. It should print out the response object so you can see precisely what parameters are returned.

Comment: i did that and nothing is happening, the console log is empty, but when i use my initial code and pass ajaxRequest to consolo.log, i get the following on the console: XMLHttpRequest {statusText: "", status: 0, response: "", responseType: "", responseXML: null…}
 places.js:31

Comment: You're right, I made two mistakes. The boolean condition does not work in places.php and I should have added response to the sendAjaxDone() function. I've updated the code now and it works here when I test it.

Comment: wow after two days finally i get help.....thanx alot, thank you thank you thank you, you taught me alot today

Comment: sorry it took me this long to come back here, i accepted the answer, thanx alot again